# Nested Object Literal Access Parent

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I'm trying to access a parent within an object literal graph and I am not sure the correct way to accomplish this. Here is some pseudo code.

```
function MealPlan() {
  this.sets = []
}

MealPlan.prototype = {
  protein: {
    getTotalSets: function() {
      return this.sets.length;
    }
  }
};
```

I am trying to get a hold of the sets property from within the getTotalSets function.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add a `return` statement to your function... But that's it. :)

Comment: sorry that's not it just a quick plunk i threw together :)

Comment: @BrunoToffolo - `this` takes on the context of `MealPlan.prototype.protein` - which is not the context the OP wants.

Comment: Use separate functions on the prototype called `getTotalProteinSets`, `getCarbsSets` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually can't be done (without hacking using `call` or `apply` the way @RichardMacarthy showed) because you are creating a new context by creating a new object context (e.g. `protein`) on the prototype. The `prototype` is used to add methods to an object, not properties.

Alternatively, you could turn your `property` in a `method` which would allow you to retain the original context of the object.

```
function MealPlan() {
  this.sets = []
}

MealPlan.prototype = {
  protein: function() { 
     var self = this; 
     return { 
        getTotalSets: function() { return self.sets.length; },
        anotherMethod: function() { /* ... */ },
     }
   }
};

var mp = new MealPlan();
mp.protein().getTotalSets();
```

Comment: ah ok i was just trying to group related methods together because there will be a group for protein, carbs, fats

Comment: This is a good answer, and is the way to go if you want to stick with using the prototype (which is slightly more memory efficient). I also added a new answer below showing how you could implement it so `mp.protein.getTotalSets()` would still work (also, consider using traits).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you call the function from you can do it like this:  Using `call` to set the context of `this` inside your function.

```
function MealPlan() {
  this.sets = []
}

MealPlan.prototype = {
  protein: {
    getTotalSets: function() {
        console.log(this)
        this.sets.length;
    }
  }
};

var m = new MealPlan();

console.log(m.protein.getTotalSets.call(m));
```

Comment: hmm thats definetly not the api i want to expose up stream. is there any other way you would structure the graph to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways you could go about this...here's a way that may have been closest to your original intent:

```
function MealPlan() {
    var self = this;
    self.sets = [];

    self.protein = {
        getTotalSets: function() { return self.sets.length; },
        anotherMethod: function() { /* ... */ },
    }
}

var mp = new MealPlan();
mp.protein.getTotalSets();
```

You could alternatively implement `protein` as a trait; take a look at http://soft.vub.ac.be/~tvcutsem/traitsjs/.